# Mongoose with out api to to the back end

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, next.js13

Is it possible to send data to MongoDB with  mongoose with out a api ?
I know redis will work but I want to know if I can use mongoose for it !

```
  await redis.hincrby(key, JSON.stringify(event), 1)
```

the code upper is wat we use at the moment to get it in the redis database

For example I start first toe send events but later I need all off it.

```
import AnalyticsModel  from "@/models/analutics";
import { connectMongoDB } from "@/lib/database/mongodb/DBConnection";

export class Analytics {
    async track( event: object = {}) {
        try {
        await connectMongoDB();
             // Create a new document using the AnalyticsModel
            const analyticsData = new AnalyticsModel(event);

            // Save the analytics data to the database
            await analyticsData.save();
        console.log(event)
        console.log('Analytics data saved successfully');
        } catch (error) {
            // console.error('Error occurred:', error);
            // throw error;
        }
    }
}


export const analytics = new Analytics()
```

Code above sadly dont work getting the following error:
Error connecting to MongoDB: [TypeError: mongoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...).connect is not a function]

I tested the event: object = {} and it keep reciving information now I only need it to send to mongoDB

Thank you for your time and reading my question !

I tried to build it many times but I failed, still learning still have so much to learn but I'M getting there. have looked with ai and the network and have look at many repos on github but still didnot find anything.